# Why range.length value changes for backspace in shouldChangeCharactersInRange delegate methos?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, nsrange

I'm trying to figure out this line which works pretty well for backspace after I restrict user up to 24 characters. But I don't know how it really works.

I tried to figure out the value of `range.length` and it's set to 0 if I insert some characters. But I get the value set to 1 when I press the back button while deleting the characters?? Why is this?

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    println("range is \(range)")
    println("range location is \(range.location)")
    println("range length is \(range.length)")    

    if (textlength - (range.length) + count(string)) > 24 {                  
       textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
       textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

       println("\(newString)")
       return false
    }        
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to insert e text 3 characters long. Then select all and hit *cut*.
You should see something like:

```
range is (0,3)
range location is 0
range length is 3
```

When you insert you get length 0 since nothing is selected. You just have the *cursor* position. When you delete your range.length will be the length of the string that could be deleted.
When you hit back you just delete the last character, thus the range.length is 1.

Comment: By the way, from your code it is not clear where `textlength` and `newString` come from. Anyway hope my hint helps.

Comment: umm..thanks really smart testing....one more question...
let modified = current.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)..
If so then how does this line works...before replacing charactes does it selects the whole length and then appends the new string...or is the range value set to 0 during this statement too

Comment: ups, probably you are referring to @DarkDust 's example. Anyway the `range` passed by `shouldChange...` is position and length of what _shouldChange_. Beware not confusing it with the length of the replacement string. As another example, you could try to select 3 characters and then hit a letter (instead of back). This time the range passed will have length 3 (since 3 characters will be replaced), and replacement string will be the single character. `modified ...` will replace the 3 characters selected (in `range` from `current`) with the single character `replacementString`

Answer (score 2):

The method says **shouldChangeCharacterInRange**, so when you insert a new character, no existing characters are to be replaced or deleted, therefore it gives you length as 0. Whereas when you delete a character, it will return you the range of the character to be deleted, and it will obviously be 1.

**Ex:**

Lets say you have a text **Hello World**
This contains 11 characters.

Now when you insert a new character **!**, it will return you the range after the last character where this new character is going to be inserted, i.e. `{11,0}`.

Now when you delete a character, lets say the last character, it will return you the range for that last character, i.e. `{10,1}`.

You can test this by long pressing some text and deleting it. Lets say if you long press "**World**" and delete it. This will return you range with length 5 i.e.`{5,5}`.

---

Therefore you need to check the text after appending the changes, i.e.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let stringAfterAppendingChanges = textField.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    if (stringAfterAppendingChanges.length > 24 {                  
       textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
       textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

       println("\(stringAfterAppendingChanges)")
       return false
    }

    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor        
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this length check is by actually applying the replacement, then testing the result string.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let current = textField.text
    let modified = current.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    if (modified.length > 24 {                  
       textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
       textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

       println("\(modified)")
       return false
    }        
    return true
}
```